# Linked list in C (middle insert)

Tags: c, linked-list

> Write a program containing a linked list of integers that allows you to duplicate X element next to the X element in the list (X is given by user). Example: List:1,4,3,2,5,3,7; X=3. Resulting list: 1,4,3,3,2,5,3,3,7.

Thats the problem I need to solve but I tried EVERYTHING. Linked lists it's something that doesn't enter my head. I know how to add a number in the end and in the beggining but in this question I don't even know where to start. That's what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
  int x;
  struct node *next;
}Node;

// Check if the list is empty
int empty(Node *list){
  if(list->next == NULL)
    return 1;
  else
    return 0;
}

// Insert a number
void insert(Node *list){
  Node *newn=(Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
  printf("\nNumber: "); 
  scanf("%d", &newn->x);
  newn->next = NULL;

  if(empty(list))
    list->next=newn;
  else{
    Node *aux = list->next;
    while(aux->next != NULL){
      aux = aux->next;
    }
    aux->next = newn;
  }
}

// Print the list
void print(Node *list){
  Node *next = list;
  int i=1;

  printf("\n");
  if(empty(list)){
    printf("EMPTY!\n");
  }else{
    list = list->next;
    while(list!=NULL){
      printf("NUMBER [%2d]: %d\n", i++, list->x);
      list = list->next;
    }
  }
}

// Duplicate X values in the list
void duplicate(Node *lista){

}

int main(void) {
  Node *list = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));

  int op, val;

  do{
    printf("\n1 - Insert\n");
    printf("2 - Print\n");
    printf("3 - Duplicate X\n");
    printf("5 - Close\n");
    printf("OPERATION: ");
    scanf("%d", &op);
    switch(op){
      case 1:
        insert(list);
        break;
      case 2:
        print(list);
        break;
      case 3:
        duplicate(list);
        break;
      case 5:
        printf("Closed!\n");
        break;
      default:
        printf("Invalid option!\n");
    }
  }while(op != 5);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: One thing that can really help a lot with understanding linked lists is drawing them out. Lots of boxes (nodes) and arrows (pointers).

Comment: list: `1,4,3,2,5,3,7` ==> `1,4,3 break list here (virtually) 2,5,3,7`, add `3` to end of first list and **the same `3`** to the beginning of second list :-)

Comment: `Invalid option\n` should be printed to stderr.  But how does your program behave if the user enters `A` for the option?  You should check the value returned by scanf, and consume bad data rather than entering a loop repeatedly emitting the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before suggesting the solution, I would first suggest to change some things in your code:

- Don't ask for input in the dedicated functions (like `insert`). Do that in your `main`.
- Split some logic in separate functions:

  - `createNode` for creating a node,
  - `getTail` for finding the reference to the last node in the list

  Then use these to make your `insert` function quite simple. You can then also reuse `createNode` for creating the "sentinel" `list` node at the start of your program, and you can use it also for implementing `duplicate`.

Here is the suggested code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
  int x;
  struct node *next;
}Node;

// Check if the list is empty
int empty(Node *list){
  if(list->next == NULL)
    return 1;
  else
    return 0;
}

// Get a reference to the last node in the list, 
//   even if it is the sentinel node
Node *getTail(Node * list) {
  Node *tail = list;
  while (tail->next != NULL) {
    tail = tail->next;
  }
  return tail;
}

// Generic function for creating a Node instance
Node *createNode(int val, Node *next) {
  Node *newn = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
  newn->x = val;
  newn->next = next;
  return newn;
}

// Insert a number
void insert(Node *list, int val) {
  getTail(list)->next = createNode(val, NULL);
}

// Print the list (I changed the output format)
void print(Node *list) {
  list = list->next;
  while (list!=NULL) {
    printf("%d -> ", list->x);
    list = list->next;
  }
  printf("NULL\n");
}

// Duplicate X values in the list
void duplicate(Node *list, int val) {
  list = list->next;
  while (list != NULL) {
    if (list->x == val) {
      list->next = createNode(val, list->next);
      list = list->next; // reference the new node
    }
    list = list->next;
  }
}

int main(void) {
  Node *list = createNode(0, NULL); // Also use here!

  int op, val;

  do{
    printf("\n1 - Insert\n");
    printf("2 - Print\n");
    printf("3 - Duplicate X\n");
    printf("5 - Close\n");
    printf("OPERATION: ");
    scanf("%d", &op);
    switch(op){
      case 1:
        // Perform input in main program
        printf("\nNumber to insert: "); 
        scanf("%d", &val);
        insert(list, val);
        break;
      case 2:
        print(list);
        break;
      case 3:
        printf("\nNumber to duplicate: "); 
        scanf("%d", &val);
        duplicate(list, val);
        break;
      case 5:
        printf("Closed!\n");
        break;
      default:
        printf("Invalid option!\n");
    }
  } while(op != 5);

  return 0;
}
```